# Is there a way to pause execution when a variable reference is changed in JavaScript or using Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a `request` object with a `url` property. When I send my request out, some other part of the code base is concatenating 'https://' to the beginning of the string. I cannot find where this object mutation is occurring though. I Chrome allows you to pause execution when DOM nodes are changed, is there a similar way in either JavaScript or Chrome to do the same thing with JavaScript objects?

Comment: in your request object override `url` with a property and put a breakpoint in setter?

Comment: The `url` property is a string which is being accessed directly (and reassigned directly). No setter methods.

Comment: re-define it with a property on your exact object. It's javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Re-define the url for a custom property and break when a value is assigned:

```
request._url = request.url;

Object.defineProperty(request, "url", {
    get: function () {
        return this._url;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        debugger;
        this._url = value;
    }
});
```